# mongo db to case class coversion error

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, spray

I am using mongoDB and mapping its response to case class in scala
I am getting exception of cant conver Integer to String.
so how can I make my case class Independent of datatype in database, I try with 'Any' datatype , then it shows me error while converting to json.

Comment: Is it possible to provide your own JSON reader.

Comment: Which MongoDB driver?

Comment: You need to provide snippet of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what's wrong with your code without any example, but here is a working example. Maybe you'll find what you need:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.DateTime
import reactivemongo.bson.{ BSONDocument, BSONDocumentReader, BSONDocumentWriter, BSONObjectID }

case class Role( id: BSONObjectID = BSONObjectID.generate,
             name: String,
             statusOrder: Int )

object Role {

implicit object RoleBSONReader extends BSONDocumentReader[ Role ] {

def read( doc: BSONDocument ): Role =
  Role(
    id = doc.getAs[ BSONObjectID ]( "_id" ).get,
    name = doc.getAs[ String ]( "name" ).get,
    statusOrder = doc.getAs[ Int ]( "status_order" ).get
  )
}

implicit object RoleBSONWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[ Role ] {
    def write( role: Role ): BSONDocument =
      BSONDocument(
        "_id" -> role.id,
        "name" -> role.name,
        "status_order" -> role.statusOrder
      )
    }

}
```